# Extract a pattern using awk in a specific column

Tags: awk

**I would like to modify a file (gff3 format) by taking only one specific part of the last column!**

My file looks like this with the nine columns separated by tab spaces:

> NW_015494524.1 Gnomon CDS 1220137 1220159 . - 0 ID=cds20267;Parent=rna22739;Dbxref=GeneID:107513619,Genbank:XP_016006018.1;Name=XP_016006018.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=A3GALT2;product=alpha_1%2C3-galactosyltransferase_2 protein_id=XP_016006018.1

I would like to extract only my gene name (;gene=XXX;) present in the last column ($9). 
Output:

> NW_015494524.1 Gnomon CDS 1220137 1220159 . - 0 A3GALT2

After this done, I would like to combine column 4,5,7,8 and the extracted value from 9th col in a unique column
Expected Output:

> A3GALT2 1220137 1220159 - 0

I have tried to use `awk` to take only the pattern gene=xxxx in the last column. My gene name are upper case letters with or without numbers; and are delimited by ';' semicolon in the ninth column.

```
awk  FS "[ \t]" '$9 ~/gene=[A-Z0-9]$/ {print $0, $4, $5, $7, $8}' <file>
```

It is not working. Is there another way to do it with `awk` or maybe `sed` or `grep` are better ?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: You want output as `NW_015494524.1 Gnomon CDS 1220137 1220159 . - 0 A3GALT2`  OR `NW_015494524.1 Gnomon CDS 1220137 1220159 . - 0`, please explain it more to us?

Comment: Yes sorry. I was thinking to do it in two parts, but I can do it all at once. I want the gene name, positions, strand and phase. Thank for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following awk should help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/.*gene=/,"",$(NF-1));sub(/\;.*/,"",$(NF-1));$NF=""} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
NW_015494524.1 Gnomon CDS 1220137 1220159 . - 0 A3GALT2
```

***EDIT:*** As I had mentioned in comments too I am confused which output you need in case you need your second shown output following may help you in same.

```
awk '$9 ~ /.*gene=/{sub(/.*gene=/,"",$(NF-1));sub(/\;.*/,"",$(NF-1));print $9,$4,$5,$7,$8} '  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A3GALT2 1220137 1220159 - 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '{ split($9,a,";"); print substr(a[6],6),$4,$5,$7,$8 }' file
```

- `split($9,a,";")` - split the 9th field into array of chunks `a` using `;` as separator
- `substr(a[6],6)` - extracting the needed *gene* name from substring `gene=XXXXXXXX`

The output:

```
A3GALT2 1220137 1220159 - 0
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple **awk** solution

```
$ awk '{match($9,/gene=(\w+);/,a); print a[1],$4,$5,$7,$8}' file
A3GALT2 1220137 1220159 - 0
```

`{match($9,/gene=(\w+);/,a);` : This will match the regex `gene=(\w+);` in `$9` and capture group `(\w+)` which will be stored in array `a` and that's it.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so to exclude gene= of the array I needed to ad () around gene name. If I don't put a, is the capture storage by default in a array $0?

Comment: @Nico64: You don't have to put `()` in your source input file. `()` in `match ` functions tells to capture the pattern mentioned inside paranthesis. Also if we don't specify `a` in `match` function then it won't be stored but we can use `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` parameters which are set by default whenever `match` function is called. `RSTART` denotes the index of the first matched character, 0 if not matched and `RLENGTH` it's length, -1 if not matched.

Comment: ok. yes for the bracket I mean not around my gene name in the infile but in the awk command to take only the name as the pattern stored.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies and help. Yes I would like the output as you made it. Keep only the gene name, position, strand and phase info. they will be used as header for new fasta seqs. I will try those commands.